# Display a custom product field before short description in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product

I've a problem with adding a new field in WooCommerce, before short description.

I used script in `functions.php` and my new custom field is displayed correctly but:

- Short description disappear when use script, a new field is display fine.
- I can edit the content of a field on a product page, but I can't delete it. It is always the last value.

How can I display this custom field without removing the product short description?
How can I reset this custom field content?

Here is my code:

```
// Add a custom Field
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field', 
            'label'       => __( 'Termin dostawy', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => 'np: 7 dni',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Wpisz przewidywany termin dostawy, np: 7 dni.', 'woocommerce' ) 
        )
    );

}

// Save the custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
    if( ! empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );

}

// Display the custom field
add_action('woocommerce_short_description', 'magik_custom_text', 10, 1);
function magik_custom_text()
{
     global $product;

     global $woocommerce, $post;
     echo "Termin dostawy: ".get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
}
```

Function responsible for display:

```
add_action('woocommerce_short_description', 'magik_custom_text', 10, 1);
function magik_custom_text()
{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2:**

1) You should add it to short description instead of replacing it…

The correct way is to hook your custom function in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary`** cation hook before the short description (using a priority between 11 to 19):

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'magik_custom_text', 18);
function magik_custom_text()
{
    global $post;
    $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
    // Displaying the custom field only when is set with a value
    if( ! empty( $field_value ) )
        echo '<p>' . __('Termin dostawy: ', 'woocommerce') . $field_value . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works. So you will get this:

[image]

[image]

---

2) To be able to delete the content of your product custom field you need to replace:

```
 if( ! empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
```

by:

```
 if( isset( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
```

in this hooked function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
    if( isset( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );

}
```

Comment: You' re the best! It's working better than I wanted. Addidiontal question: can you add a script: don't show an empty field?

Comment: @interlaw Yes of course, I have updated the first function in this answer, try it please…

Comment: I am so grateful for everything you've done for me, @loictheaztec :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this topic, it was very useful. I have three questions:

1. I am trying to implement in on Astra theme,  and if I use Priority 10-19, custom field is displayed under Add to cart button, if I use Priority 1-9, custom field is displayed above the product title.
2. what should I change in the code to make several custom fields like this? I changed function names, and created four fields, I see them in Editor and onsite. But all field have one values, the last one I put in in the editor. E.g., I made fields  f1, f2, f3, f4, in Edit product page I go to the product and assign values v1, v2, v3, v4. But on the frontend I see pairs f1: v4, f2:v4, f3:v4, f4:v4.