# Add a product custom field to Admin product bulk edit form in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product

I have added a custom field in my WooCommerce products like in this question/answer:
 [Display a custom product field before short description in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903747/display-a-custom-product-field-before-short-description-in-woocommerce).

Is it possible to add this custom field to the product bulk edit special page *(accessible from Admin products list page)*?

Comment: what do you mean by mass?

Comment: @Reigel I select several products and I choose edit from the horizontal menu. You look: 1. https://ibb.co/jqd0wv - select and click "edit" button. 2 - I can edit several products at one time - https://ibb.co/cT0KpF

Comment: search google for `wordpress bulk action tut`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's possible to bulk edit products for your custom field **`'_text_field'`** *(as in your linked question/answer)*.

You can add this custom field at the beginning or at the end of edit page.

- For the beginning you will use this hook: **`woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_start`**
- For the end this one: **`woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_end`**

The code *(the custom field is at the beginning here)*:

```
// Add a custom field to product bulk edit special page
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_start', 'custom_field_product_bulk_edit', 10, 0 );
function custom_field_product_bulk_edit() {
    ?>
        <div class="inline-edit-group">
            <label class="alignleft">
                <span class="title"><?php _e('T. dostawy', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>
                <span class="input-text-wrap">
                    <select class="change_t_dostawy change_to" name="change_t_dostawy">
                    <?php
                        $options = array(
                            ''  => __( '— No change —', 'woocommerce' ),
                            '1' => __( 'Change to:', 'woocommerce' ),
                        );
                        foreach ( $options as $key => $value ) {
                            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </label>
            <label class="change-input">
                <input type="text" name="_t_dostawy" class="text t_dostawy" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter Termin dostawy', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="" />
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php
}

// Save the custom fields data when submitted for product bulk edit
add_action('woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save', 'save_custom_field_product_bulk_edit', 10, 1);
function save_custom_field_product_bulk_edit( $product ){
    if ( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') ){
        $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['_t_dostawy'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_text_field', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['_t_dostawy'] ) );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works. You will get this:

[image]

Comment: @LoicTheAztec how would this change if you wanted to update a number (like a custom price field) by a percentage or increased by a fixed value (so using the current value and adding to it)?  -- also if there were multiple options, how would I be able to see which option was chosen? Is there anything in the $_REQUEST['fieldname'] to tell me which option was chosen?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, and without any hooks and code:

- Install plugin WooCommerce Bulk Editor (WOOBE): https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-bulk-editor/
- Go to tab Meta Fields and add your meta key there, press Save button
- In tab Settings activate column with that new meta key
- Using tab Bulk Edit do your manipulations

That is all :)

p.s. docs: https://bulk-editor.com/document/meta-fields/