# Updating in bulk edit values from custom meta fields in WordPress does not close bulk edit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I added two columns and custom fields in quick edit. One based on text and one as dropdown. They work just fine in quick edit and I rely on

https://github.com/bamadesigner/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit/blob/master/bulk_quick_edit.js

**My script when changed is the following**

```
(function($) {

// we create a copy
var $wp_inline_edit = inlineEditPost.edit;

//overwrite the function
inlineEditPost.edit = function( id ) {


    $wp_inline_edit.apply( this, arguments );


    // get the post ID
    var $post_id = 0;
    if ( typeof( id ) == 'object' )
        $post_id = parseInt( this.getId( id ) );

    if ( $post_id > 0 ) {

        // define the edit row
        var $edit_row = $( '#edit-' + $post_id );

        // get the sku
        var $bfsku = $( '#_text_field-' + $post_id ).text();

        // set the sku
        $edit_row.find( 'input[name="test_column"]' ).val( $bfsku );

        // get the supplier
        var $supplier = $( '#_select-' + $post_id ).text();

        // set the supplier
        $edit_row.find( 'select[name="test_column2"]' ).val( $supplier );

    }

};






$( '#bulk_edit' ).live( 'click', function() {

    // define the bulk edit row
    var $bulk_row = $( '#bulk-edit' );

    // get the selected post ids that are being edited
    var $post_ids = new Array();
    $bulk_row.find( '#bulk-titles' ).children().each( function() {
        $post_ids.push( $( this ).attr( 'id' ).replace( /^(ttle)/i, '' ) );
    });

    // get the custom fields
    var $bfsku = $bulk_row.find( 'input[name="test_column"]' ).val();

    var $supplier = $bulk_row.find( 'select[name="test_column2"]' ).val();

    // save the data
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl, // this is a variable that WordPress has already defined for us
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            action: 'manage_wp_posts_using_bulk_quick_save_bulk_edit', // this is the name of our WP AJAX function that we'll set up next
            post_ids: $post_ids, // and these are the 2 parameters we're passing to our function
            test_column: $bfsku,
            test_column2: $supplier
        }
    });

});

})(jQuery);
```

**And the Function is the following**

```
function manage_wp_posts_using_bulk_quick_save_bulk_edit() {
// we need the post IDs
$post_ids = ( isset( $_POST[ 'post_ids' ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ 'post_ids' ] ) ) ? $_POST[ 'post_ids' ] : NULL;

// if we have post IDs
if ( ! empty( $post_ids ) && is_array( $post_ids ) ) {

    // get the custom fields
    $custom_fields = array( 'test_column', 'test_column2' );

    foreach( $custom_fields as $field ) {

        // if it has a value, doesn't update if empty on bulk
        if ( isset( $_POST[ $field ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ $field ] ) ) {

            // update the price
            if ( isset( $_POST['test_column'] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', $_POST['test_column'] );

            }

            // update the price
            if ( isset( $_POST['test_column2'] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select', $_POST['test_column2'] );

            }

        }

    }

}

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_manage_wp_posts_using_bulk_quick_save_bulk_edit', 'manage_wp_posts_using_bulk_quick_save_bulk_edit' );
```

My problem is that Update button seems not working, I am confused with variable names and slugs (I believe they are correct)

**Why is not closing the bulk edit when update is finished??**

The changes are saved by the following instead the above BUT the bulk edit stays open and the update button it does not show the little spinning circle, so I need to refresh the page for the changes to be shown.

```
// Save the custom fields data when submitted for product bulk edit
add_action('woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save', 'save_custom_field_product_bulk_edit', 10, 1);
function save_custom_field_product_bulk_edit( $product ){
if ( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') ){
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['test_column'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_text_field', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['test_column'] ) );

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['test_column2'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_select', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['test_column2'] ) );
}
}
```

Comment: Note that **products** are a woocommerce **custom post type** not a normal Wordpress **post** type. So you should first search [in this related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+bulk+edit+products).

Comment: You mean the hook is different?

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051525/add-a-product-custom-field-to-admin-product-bulk-edit-form-in-woocommerce or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747572/custom-stock-options-doesnt-show-up-in-bulk-edit-woocommerce-3-2-1

Comment: I dont need a javascript ?

Comment: If I use example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051525/add-a-product-custom-field-to-admin-product-bulk-edit-form-in-woocommerce , its updating BUT the bulk edit is not closing and I need to refresh the page

Comment: You should need to edit/update your question with the actual **the complete testable code** that you are using (including fields)…