# Adding woocommerce custom field to the bulk editor

Tags: php, woocommerce

I followed the solution bellow to add a custom field to the bulk editor. It works, the custom field `_min_order_field` is being bulk edited. The problem that I am having is that when another field is bulk edited (and the custom field is left unchanged) the value in the custom field is deleted. For example, if I bulk edit the price the value in the custom field disappears. This is what i have, any pointer in the right direction will be appreciated.

This is the guide I followed:
[Add a product custom field to Admin product bulk edit form in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051525/add-a-product-custom-field-to-admin-product-bulk-edit-form-in-woocommerce)

```
//Add the minimum order field to woocomerce product bulk edit
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_start', 'minimum_order_field_bulk_edit', 10, 0 );
    function minimum_order_field_bulk_edit() {
        ?>
            <div class="inline-edit-group">
                <label class="alignleft">
                    <span class="title"><?php _e('Minimum', 'woocommerce'); ?></span>
                    <span class="input-text-wrap">
                        <select class="change_minimumo change_to" name="change_minimumo">
                        <?php
                            $options = array(
                                ''  => __( '— No change —', 'woocommerce' ),
                                '1' => __( 'Change to:', 'woocommerce' ),
                            );
                            foreach ( $options as $key => $value ) {
                                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '">' . $value . '</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <label class="change-input">
                    <input type="text" name="_minimumo" class="text minimumo" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter minimum order', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="" />
                </label>
            </div>
        <?php
    }

    // Save the minimum order fields data when submitted for product bulk edit
    add_action('woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_save', 'save_minimum_order_field_bulk_edit', 10, 1);
    function save_minimum_order_field_bulk_edit( $product ){
        if ( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') ){
            $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

            if ( isset( $_REQUEST['_minimumo'] ) )
                update_post_meta( $product_id, '_min_order_field', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['_minimumo'] ) );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small mistake in your code. In if condition you check the value with `isset()` function. In this case you have always true and you update the value with empty string. But if you check the value with `!empty()` function, you will get false if input is empty, so your previously saved data will remain.

So your code should be like that:

```
if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['_minimumo'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $product_id, '_min_order_field', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['_minimumo'] ) );
```

Comment: Yes, it is woking as it should. Thanks you for commenting on the fix.

Comment: I've noticed the `woocommerce_product_bulk_edit_start` doesn't work since I updated WooCommerce. Does anyone know how to edit the Bulk Edit fields with the new version?